# Pass data Model element to CellTemplate KoGrid

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, kogrid

I'm using [KoGrid](http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid) in order to make my custom Ajax grid.I don't know how to pass model element to some Javascrit method for generating a custom Template.

I tried like this and doesn't work:

`PluginGrid.AjaxUrl("MyControler/GetGrid").Columns(
       [
           { field: "UserName", displayName: "Model", width: "*", cellClass: "text-center", headerClass: "grid_width_270", cellTemplate: PluginHelpers.HtmlUserInformation($parent.entity, true) },
           { field: "StatusId", displayName: "Status", width: "*", cellClass: "text-center", headerClass: "text-center" }
       ]).Show("grid");
    });`

This is actually a wrapper over KoGrid.I want to pass the data model somehow, to my Js method :

```
 PluginHelpers.HtmlUserInformation($parent.entity, true) }
```

When I do like this I received some undefined error of $parent variable.

Please advice,

Comment: `$parent` is defined for use in the HTML `data-bind`, not in the JS code. Can you show the relevant HTML?

Comment: Actually I found it:) At the end I created a new html template and put data-bind on html with Js call...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution for this:

`<template id="XXX">
    <div data-bind="html: PluginHelpers.HtmlUserInformation($parent.entity, true)">
    </div>
</template>`

and then

`PluginGrid.AjaxUrl("Controller/GetGrid").Columns(
       [
           { field: "UserName", displayName: "Model", width: "*", cellClass: "text-center", headerClass: "grid_width_270", cellTemplate: $("#XXX").html() },
           { field: "StatusId", displayName: "Status", width: "*", cellClass: "text-center", headerClass: "text-center" }
       ]).Show("grid");`

This is the best solution I could find....